# Building IOS AIR app from FlashDevelop error: Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: ios, actionscript, air, starling-framework, away3d

I'm just posting this and self-answering it for posterity's sake.

I looked around the internet and couldn't find an answer, but was able to get around it. So I thought I'd throw it up in case anyone else searches for it.

When building an AIR mobile app from FlashDevelop and coming across this error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Compliation failed while executing : ADT

APK setup creation FAILED.
```

Comment: Are you using the latest FlashDevelop and AIR SDK?  If this is a bug you should post it on the FladhDevelop forums so the admins can take a look.  They read everything and you will receive a response.

Comment: I've seen one or two other posts regarding this bug, and they all recommended the memory allocation fix with no success (posted below). This is how I got it work. I think my ide and sdk are up to date, I set up my workspace only a month or so ago. I'll drop a line on the forums, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "Run.bat" under

```
:target
```

change from

```
goto ios-debug
```

to

```
goto ios-test
```

If that doesn't work:

```
reboot

rebuild
```

It can be finnicky, but this is how I got it working. Changing the java config file's memory allocation did nothing.

Comment: did this work for you? where do i find the run.bat file?

Answer (score 0):

- open `FlexSDK/bin/jvm.config`
- change `Xmx384m` to `Xmx512m`
- reboot computer
- If that does not work, check whether the system disk space is too small, or the virtual memory settings to other disk space under